# What are the process involved in tire rotation during long term storage?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

During Covid-19 crisis in 2020 a lot of planes are grounded for a long time. Tires of parked planes can develop flat spot hence the need to keep these tire rotate. What are the processes involved regarding tire rotation during this time? 
Is the plane towed 100 feet every week or rotate each tire 45 degree every day or something else?

[image: AirAsia plane grounded during covid19]
Aircraft with tire marking.

Source: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1908245919474139&type=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manufacturers give the manual for storing/parking periodic ground check.

For Airbus A320 family:

> You can ignore this step if you moved the aircraft for the APU start.
>
> Turn the wheels by 1/4 turn to prevent damage to the tires:
>
> a) Move the aircraft Ref. AMM xxxx or b) Refer to the jacking for
>   wheel change procedures to turn each wheel separately

This is done if storing is more than 15d, and repeated once every 15d.

Comment: Where does the 1/4 turn come from? Why not 1/3 turn or other fraction?

Comment: @Manu H, because if they chose 1/3 somebody would ask why not 1/4?  Seriously though, some things are just arbitrary and don't have an engineering reason.